# How to draw multi colored line using xml in android

Tags: java, android

[image]

Is it possible to draw a line like shown in the fig. using android xml ? I need it for setting a background for view pager indicator

Comment: In XML? Wrap three views in a horizontally oriented linear layout and assign weights to your views as per their size ratio.

Comment: Hi i need it for setting viewpager indicator background !

Answer (score 0):

If you need hard edges like that, I'd suggest using a 9-patch: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

If you're ok with soft edges, you can use a gradient (which I got from using [this online tool](http://angrytools.com/android/button/)):

```
<gradient
    android:angle="0"
    android:centerX="50%"
    android:centerColor="#000000"
    android:startColor="#FF0000"
    android:endColor="#FF0000"
    android:type="linear"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="-100dp"
        android:top="-100dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="100dp"
                android:color="#FF0000" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and then add this as background.